# Can you add a label or div to newform.aspx in add-in and set the value with JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint addin which deploys a lists . Now i  want to display some information with Javascript on that page, lets say set the value of a label.

The newform comes with a default layout. Is it possible to add a div or p or label and set the value there or i can only use alert to display the message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom new item form page for the list in add-in.

Check the article below:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-custom-new-edit-display-form-to-list-using-sharepoint-ho/